# Back referencing with peg.js

Tags: javascript, peg

Given the input `[tag] Content [inner-tag] Inner [/inner-tag][/tag]`, how would I verify that there is a closing `[/tag]` that matches `[tag]`?

Right now my rules check to see if the next immediate tag matches the last opening tag:

```
tagblock =
  opentag:opentag content:content? closetag:closetag
    { if(opentag.name != closetag.name) {
        throw new this.SyntaxError("No closing tag found for " + opentag.name); 
      } else { 
        return { name:opentag.name, content:content }
      }
    }
```

This works with `[tag] Content [/tag]` but not with nested input above.

How do you handle inner recursion like this with peg.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the one I came up with.

```
Content =
  (Element / Text)*

Element =
  startTag:sTag content:Content endTag:eTag {
    if (startTag != endTag) {
      throw new Error(
        "Expected [/" + startTag + "] but [/" + endTag + "] found."
      );
    }

    return {
      name:    startTag,
      content: content
    };
  }

sTag =
  "[" name:TagName "]" { return name; }

eTag =
  "[/" name:TagName "]" { return name; }

TagName = chars:[a-z-]+ { return chars.join(""); }
Text    = chars:[^[]+  { return chars.join(""); }
```

After loading that into nodejs:

```
var PEG=require('./markup.js'); 
var str = '[tag] Content [inner-tag] Inner [/inner-tag][/tag]';
PEG.parse(str);
```

the result is:

```
[ { name: 'tag',
    content: [
        ' Content ',
        { name: 'inner-tag',
          content: [ ' Inner ' ] }
    ]
} ]
```

Comment: Thank you! I think we both found the [XML example](https://gist.github.com/dmajda/7688943). My new problem is how to allow for single elements, i.e, ones without a closing tag. As in `[tag] Content [single][/tag]`. I've been experimenting with negative lookaheads, but no success yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, but it would be best to make a different question for that; or, at the very least, update this question & title to encapsulate that question.

Comment: Ha, was in the process of doing just that, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089940/xml-single-node-parsing-with-peg-js. Thanks.